# Cholesky update for an added diagonal

Tags: matrices

I have to (numerically) compute 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(z)(zK+\sigma^2I)^{-1}u\,dz$$ 
where $u$ is a constant vector, $z$ is a scalar and $f(\cdot)$ is a known function.

The problem that I have is for each increment of $z$ I have to keep recalculating the Cholesky of $zK+\sigma^2I$.

If the Cholesky of $K$ is known is there a method of not continuously doing this for each new value of $z$?

I should mention that $K$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix, and usually dense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer that directly addresses your question, but if you could use eigendecomposition instead of Cholesky decomposition, so that $K=QDQ^\ast$ (where $Q$ is unitary and $D$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix), then
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty f(z) (zK+\sigma^2 I)^{-1} u dz
&= \int_0^\infty f(z) Q (zD+\sigma^2 I)^{-1} Q^\ast u dz.
\end{align*}
If $f(z)$ is a real-valued function, the RHS can be further rewritten as
$$
Q \left(\int_0^\infty f(z) (zD+\sigma^2 I)^{-1} dz\right) Q^\ast u.
$$

Comment: but doesn't $K=QDQ^*$ make it a diagonal matrix? K is a dense matrix :(

Comment: Yes, $D$ is diagonal. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @user72388 $D$ is a diagonal matrix, but $K$ is not necessarily one.

Comment: Actually never mind. You are right, and this is certainly what I am looking for. Thank you so much :D

Comment: Ah! This only works if the $\sigma^2 I$ term is spherical, so that it can also be diagonalized by $Q$. I'm also working on some Gaussian process code, but have non-uniform measurement variances, so alas cannot use this approach (and I fear there may be none).